# Absolutely-positioned element is affected by padding on parent

Tags: html, css

my question is why changing padding in div.container affects div.blueBox? Since blueBox positioning is set to absolute it is taken out of normal flow, and should be positioned with relation to  element.

HTML:

```
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box blueBox"></div> 
        </div>      
        <div class="box greenBox"></div> 

        <h1>Understanding CSS Positioning</h1>
        <p><em>Absolute positioning</em> takes an element out of document flow, meaning the browser acts as if the element has no width and height, and the other elements on the page move up as if it was never there.  The position of the element is then fixed relative to the top level container, or the closest parent with a set positioning.</p>

    </body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    height: 2000px;
    color: #bfbfbf;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: normal;   
}

em {
    color: #dd740b;   
}

.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.blueBox {
    background: #627da0;
    position: absolute;
}

.greenBox {
    background: #5b8054;  
}

.container {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    padding: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pawelpodsiadly/brdc8dvy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolute positioning puts an element in place with respect to its closest ancestor *that also has positioning other than static*.

If you want `.blueBox` positioned relative to the body, set top and left values:

```css
body {
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  color: #bfbfbf;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.blueBox {
  background: #627da0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.container {
  background: pink;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box blueBox"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box greenBox"></div>
  <h1>Understanding CSS Positioning</h1>

  <p><em>Absolute positioning</em> takes an element out of document flow, meaning the browser acts as if the element has no width and height, and the other elements on the page move up as if it was never there. The position of the element is then fixed relative
    to the top level container, or the closest parent with a set positioning.</p>
</body>
```

If you wanted it positioned with respect to `.container`, you'll need to position `.container`:

```css
body {
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  color: #bfbfbf;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.blueBox {
  background: #627da0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.container {
  background: pink;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box blueBox"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box greenBox"></div>
  <h1>Understanding CSS Positioning</h1>

  <p><em>Absolute positioning</em> takes an element out of document flow, meaning the browser acts as if the element has no width and height, and the other elements on the page move up as if it was never there. The position of the element is then fixed relative
    to the top level container, or the closest parent with a set positioning.</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

When adding a position absolute, you need to define:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the rest of the `position` elements. Like `top` or `left`, etc.

You may also be wanting `relative` and not `absolute`.

```
.blueBox {
    background: #627da0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/brdc8dvy/3/)